# Cannot spread object literal because Flow cannot determine a type for object literal

Tags: javascript, flow-js

The following (simplified) code

```
type Category = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
};

type Option = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    isSelected: boolean,
};

const options = categories.map((c: Category): Option => ({
 isSelected: true,
 ...c,
}));
```

produces the error:

> Flow: Cannot spread object literal because Flow cannot determine a type for object literal [1]. `Category` [2] is inexact, so it may contain `isSelected` with a type that conflicts with `isSelected`'s definition in object literal [1]. Try making `Category` [2] exact.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your category type is inexact, which means that it may contain properties not defined in your type. The error shows up because if c contains a property named `isSelected`, it may result in an Option object not having a boolean value for that property.

There are two possible fixes:

```
const options = categories.map((c: Category): Option => ({
   ...c,
 isSelected: true,
}));
```

This will result in `isSelected: true` always taking precedence over `c.isSelected` if it ever existed.

The second fix is to make Category exact.

```
type Category = {|
    id: string,
    name: string,
|};
```

Doing this will forbid it to have extra properties. You should try to make your objects exact whenever possible.

For more information, you can read https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types